# How to send record to Kinesis in fire-and-forget mode with AWS SDK v3 for NodeJS

Tags: node.js, async-await, aws-sdk, amazon-kinesis

today I'm able to put a record in Kinesis, but this operation takes 30 ms (which is too much for my use case), and I would like to **not wait** for the kinesis response (= fire-and-forget)

Today I use the `PutRecordCommand` solution:

```
const putRecordCommand = new PutRecordCommand({
  Data: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(report)),
  PartitionKey: requestId,
  StreamName: STREAM_NAME,
});

await kinesisClient.send(putRecordCommand);
```

If I remove the `await` key word, and the lambda ends before the kinesis client retrieves a response, I get the following error:

```json
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection",
    "errorMessage": "Error [ERR_HTTP2_STREAM_CANCEL]: The pending stream has been canceled (caused by: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established)",
    "reason": {
        "errorType": "Error",
        "errorMessage": "The pending stream has been canceled (caused by: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established)",
        "code": "ERR_HTTP2_STREAM_CANCEL",
        "cause": {
            "errorType": "Error",
            "errorMessage": "Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established",
            "code": "ECONNRESET",
            "host": "kinesis.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
            "port": "443",
            "stack": [
                "Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established",
                "    at connResetException (node:internal/errors:692:14)",
                "    at TLSSocket.onConnectEnd (node:_tls_wrap:1587:19)",
                "    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:539:35)",
                "    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1345:12)",
                "    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)"
            ]
        },
        "$metadata": {
            "attempts": 1,
            "totalRetryDelay": 0
        },
        "stack": [
            "Error [ERR_HTTP2_STREAM_CANCEL]: The pending stream has been canceled (caused by: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established)",
            "    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)",
            "    at closeSession (node:internal/http2/core:1136:20)",
            "    at ClientHttp2Session.destroy (node:internal/http2/core:1530:5)",
            "    at TLSSocket.socketOnError (node:internal/http2/core:2981:13)",
            "    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)",
            "    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)",
            "    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)",
            "    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)"
        ]
    },
    "promise": {},
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: Error [ERR_HTTP2_STREAM_CANCEL]: The pending stream has been canceled (caused by: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established)",
        "    at process.<anonymous> (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:775:15)",
        "    at process.emit (node:events:527:28)",
        "    at emit (node:internal/process/promises:140:20)",
        "    at processPromiseRejections (node:internal/process/promises:274:27)",
        "    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:97:32)"
    ]
}
```

**Questions:**

1. Is there another Kinesis "command" from AWS SDK v3 that allows me to fire-and-forget?
2. Or an option to use on the kinesis client in order to make it work without `await`?

**Notes:**

- Env: AWS Lambda with NodeJS v16
- Dependency: AWS SDK v3 v3.154
- `async`/`await` programming style

Comment: Have you tried the batch method PutRecords (note the S) rather than PutRecord one (no S)? The wait time per record becomes more negligible if you put many records at once. Fire and forget seems a bad idea, unless you don't care much about the data and can tolerate losing it.

Comment: @Elliveny Thanks for heads-up on this - worked like a charm for me.